# Wedge product and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am learning about differential forms and exterior algebra, and I am trying to get more familiar with the wedge product of vectors. A differential form is an element of $\left( \bigwedge^k (A)\right)^*$, but when they are written out, they are written as $\bigwedge^k (A^*)$, and I'm trying to get a better handle on this correspondence.

Suppose $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces. Then there is an isomorphism 
$$
\hom(A, C) \otimes \hom(B,D)\xrightarrow{\sim}\hom(A \otimes B, C \otimes D)\\
\phi \otimes \psi \mapsto (a \otimes b \mapsto \phi a \otimes \psi b).
$$
Choosing $C,D = \mathbb{F}$ gives us a statement about the dual of a tensor product: $(A \otimes B)^* = A^* \otimes B^*$, and in particular, $(A^{\otimes n})^*= (A^*)^{\otimes n}$. We could have known that they were isomorphic just by counting dimensions, but the above theorem seems to give the isomorphism more context and make it somehow natural and basis-free.

Now it also happens to be true that $\left(\bigwedge^k (A)\right)^* \cong \bigwedge^k (A^*)$. This is true just by counting dimensions, but I'm trying to understand the correspondence a little better. I'm wondering if there is a theorem like the above to put this correspondence in a broader context.

A friend pointed out to me that a dimension-counting argument implies that such a theorem couldn't be much like the form above.

Anyway, I'm just interested in understanding the correspondence $\left(\bigwedge^k (A)\right)^* \cong \bigwedge^k (A^*)$ better, and so better grokking how to work with differential forms.

Comment: You certainly need something better than dimension counting in practice.

Comment: One way is to show that there is a perfect pairing
\\[
\textstyle \bigwedge^p V \times \bigwedge^p V^* \to k
\\]
under which $(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_p, f_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge f_p) \mapsto \det(f_i(v_j))$.

Comment: @Hoot What do you mean by a "perfect pairing"?

Comment: @EricAuld A [perfect pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing#Definition) between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is a nondegenerate bilinear form $V \times W \to k$. It induces an isomorphism $V \cong W^*$ and $V^* \cong W$.